# Can MySQL execute a compressed SQL file?

Tags: mysql, compression

Is there a way to have mysql uncompress a sql statement before executing it?

My use case is that I have a table I want to move to a different server.  The table definition and data from this table are 42725 lines of SQL or about 2.5MB.

Here is a snippet:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:                         localhost
-- Server version:               5.6.24 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
-- Server OS:                    Win32
-- HeidiSQL Version:             9.3.0.5107
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;

-- Dumping structure for table us_zip_codes
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `us_zip_codes`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `us_zip_codes` (
  `zZip` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `zCity` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zState` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`zZip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Dumping data for table us_zip_codes: ~42,725 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `us_zip_codes` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `us_zip_codes` (`zZip`, `zCity`, `zState`) VALUES
    ('00501', 'HOLTSVILLE', 'NY'),
    ('00544', 'HOLTSVILLE', 'NY'),
    ('00601', 'ADJUNTAS', 'PR'),
    ('00602', 'AGUADA', 'PR'),
    ('00603', 'AGUADILLA', 'PR'),
    ('00604', 'AGUADILLA', 'PR'),
    ('00605', 'AGUADILLA', 'PR'),
    ('00606', 'MARICAO', 'PR'),
    ('00610', 'ANASCO', 'PR'),
    ('00611', 'ANGELES', 'PR'),
    ('00612', 'ARECIBO', 'PR'),
    ('00613', 'ARECIBO', 'PR'),
    ('00614', 'ARECIBO', 'PR'),
    ('00616', 'BAJADERO', 'PR'),
    ('00617', 'BARCELONETA', 'PR'),
    ('00622', 'BOQUERON', 'PR'),
    ('00623', 'CABO ROJO', 'PR'),
    ('00624', 'PENUELAS', 'PR'),
    ('00627', 'CAMUY', 'PR'),
    ('00631', 'CASTANER', 'PR'),
    ('00636', 'ROSARIO', 'PR'),
    ('00637', 'SABANA GRANDE', 'PR'),
    ('00638', 'CIALES', 'PR'),
    ('00641', 'UTUADO', 'PR'),
    ('00646', 'DORADO', 'PR'),
    ('00647', 'ENSENADA', 'PR'),
    ('00650', 'FLORIDA', 'PR'),
    ('00652', 'GARROCHALES', 'PR'),
    ('00653', 'GUANICA', 'PR'),
    ('00656', 'GUAYANILLA', 'PR'),
    ('00659', 'HATILLO', 'PR'),
    ('00660', 'HORMIGUEROS', 'PR'),
    ('00662', 'ISABELA', 'PR'),
    ('00664', 'JAYUYA', 'PR'),
    ('00667', 'LAJAS', 'PR'),
    ('00669', 'LARES', 'PR'),
    ('00670', 'LAS MARIAS', 'PR'),
    ('00674', 'MANATI', 'PR'),
    ('00676', 'MOCA', 'PR'),
    ('00677', 'RINCON', 'PR'),
    ('00678', 'QUEBRADILLAS', 'PR'),
    ('00680', 'MAYAGUEZ', 'PR'),
    ('00681', 'MAYAGUEZ', 'PR'),
    ('00682', 'MAYAGUEZ', 'PR'),
    ('00683', 'SAN GERMAN', 'PR'),
    ('00685', 'SAN SEBASTIAN', 'PR'),
    ('00687', 'MOROVIS', 'PR'),
    ('00688', 'SABANA HOYOS', 'PR'),
    ('00690', 'SAN ANTONIO', 'PR'),
    ('00692', 'VEGA ALTA', 'PR'),
    ('00693', 'VEGA BAJA', 'PR'),
    ('00694', 'VEGA BAJA', 'PR'),
    ('00698', 'YAUCO', 'PR'),
    ('00703', 'AGUAS BUENAS', 'PR'),
    ('00704', 'AGUIRRE', 'PR'),
    ('00705', 'AIBONITO', 'PR'),
    ('00707', 'MAUNABO', 'PR'),
    ('00714', 'ARROYO', 'PR'),
    ('00715', 'MERCEDITA', 'PR'),
    ('00716', 'PONCE', 'PR'),
    ('00717', 'PONCE', 'PR'),
    ('00718', 'NAGUABO', 'PR'),
    ('00719', 'NARANJITO', 'PR'),
    ('00720', 'OROCOVIS', 'PR'),
    ('00721', 'PALMER', 'PR'),
    ('00723', 'PATILLAS', 'PR'),
    ('00725', 'CAGUAS', 'PR'),
    ('00726', 'CAGUAS', 'PR'),
    ('00727', 'CAGUAS', 'PR'),
    ('00728', 'PONCE', 'PR'),
    ('00729', 'CANOVANAS', 'PR'),
    ('00730', 'PONCE', 'PR'),
    ('00731', 'PONCE', 'PR'),
    ('00732', 'PONCE', 'PR'),
    ('00733', 'PONCE', 'PR'),
    ('00734', 'PONCE', 'PR'),
    ('00735', 'CEIBA', 'PR'),
    ('00736', 'CAYEY', 'PR'),
    ('00737', 'CAYEY', 'PR'),
    ('00738', 'FAJARDO', 'PR'),
    ('00739', 'CIDRA', 'PR'),
    ('00740', 'PUERTO REAL', 'PR'),
    ('00741', 'PUNTA SANTIAGO', 'PR'),
    ('00742', 'ROOSEVELT ROADS', 'PR'),
    ('00744', 'RIO BLANCO', 'PR'),
    ('00745', 'RIO GRANDE', 'PR'),
    ('00751', 'SALINAS', 'PR'),
    ('00754', 'SAN LORENZO', 'PR'),
    ('00757', 'SANTA ISABEL', 'PR'),
    ('00765', 'VIEQUES', 'PR'),
    ('00766', 'VILLALBA', 'PR'),
    ('00767', 'YABUCOA', 'PR'),
    ('00769', 'COAMO', 'PR'),
    ('00771', 'LAS PIEDRAS', 'PR'),
    ('00772', 'LOIZA', 'PR'),
    ('00773', 'LUQUILLO', 'PR'),
    ('00775', 'CULEBRA', 'PR'),
    ('00777', 'JUNCOS', 'PR'),
    ('00778', 'GURABO', 'PR'),
    ('00780', 'COTO LAUREL', 'PR'),
    ('00782', 'COMERIO', 'PR'),
    ('00783', 'COROZAL', 'PR'),
    ('00784', 'GUAYAMA', 'PR'),
    ('00785', 'GUAYAMA', 'PR'),
    ('00786', 'LA PLATA', 'PR'),
    ('00791', 'HUMACAO', 'PR'),
    ('00792', 'HUMACAO', 'PR'),
    ('00794', 'BARRANQUITAS', 'PR'),
    ('00795', 'JUANA DIAZ', 'PR'),
    ('00801', 'ST THOMAS', 'VI'),
    ('00802', 'ST THOMAS', 'VI'),
    ('00803', 'ST THOMAS', 'VI'),
    ('00804', 'ST THOMAS', 'VI'),
    ('00805', 'ST THOMAS', 'VI'),
    ('00820', 'CHRISTIANSTED', 'VI'),
    ('00821', 'CHRISTIANSTED', 'VI'),
    ('00822', 'CHRISTIANSTED', 'VI'),
    ('00823', 'CHRISTIANSTED', 'VI'),
    ('00824', 'CHRISTIANSTED', 'VI'),
    ('00830', 'ST JOHN', 'VI'),
    ('00831', 'ST JOHN', 'VI'),
    ('00840', 'FREDERIKSTED', 'VI'),
    ('00841', 'FREDERIKSTED', 'VI'),
    ('00850', 'KINGSHILL', 'VI'),
    ('00851', 'KINGSHILL', 'VI'),
    ('00901', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00902', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00906', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00907', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00908', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00909', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00910', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00911', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00912', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00913', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00914', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00915', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00916', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00917', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00918', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00919', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00920', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00921', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00922', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00923', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00924', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00925', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00926', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00927', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00928', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00929', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00930', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00931', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00933', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00934', 'FORT BUCHANAN', 'PR'),
    ('00935', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00936', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00937', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00939', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00940', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00949', 'TOA BAJA', 'PR'),
    ('00950', 'TOA BAJA', 'PR'),
    ('00951', 'TOA BAJA', 'PR'),
    ('00952', 'SABANA SECA', 'PR'),
    ('00953', 'TOA ALTA', 'PR'),
    ('00954', 'TOA ALTA', 'PR'),
    ('00955', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00956', 'BAYAMON', 'PR'),
    ('00957', 'BAYAMON', 'PR'),
    ('00958', 'BAYAMON', 'PR'),
    ('00959', 'BAYAMON', 'PR'),
    ('00960', 'BAYAMON', 'PR'),
    ('00961', 'BAYAMON', 'PR'),
    ('00962', 'CATANO', 'PR'),
    ('00963', 'CATANO', 'PR'),
    ('00965', 'GUAYNABO', 'PR'),
    ('00966', 'GUAYNABO', 'PR'),
    ('00968', 'GUAYNABO', 'PR'),
    ('00969', 'GUAYNABO', 'PR'),
    ('00970', 'GUAYNABO', 'PR'),
    ('00971', 'GUAYNABO', 'PR'),
    ('00975', 'SAN JUAN', 'PR'),
    ('00976', 'TRUJILLO ALTO', 'PR'),
    ('00977', 'TRUJILLO ALTO', 'PR'),
    ('00978', 'SAINT JUST', 'PR'),
    ('00979', 'CAROLINA', 'PR'),
    ('00981', 'CAROLINA', 'PR'),
    ('00982', 'CAROLINA', 'PR'),
    ('00983', 'CAROLINA', 'PR'),
    ('00984', 'CAROLINA', 'PR'),
    ('00985', 'CAROLINA', 'PR'),
    ('00986', 'CAROLINA', 'PR'),
    ('00987', 'CAROLINA', 'PR'),
    ('00988', 'CAROLINA', 'PR'),
    ('01001', 'AGAWAM', 'MA'),
    ('01002', 'AMHERST', 'MA'),
    ('01003', 'AMHERST', 'MA'),
    ('01004', 'AMHERST', 'MA'),
    ('01005', 'BARRE', 'MA'),
    ('01007', 'BELCHERTOWN', 'MA'),
    ('01008', 'BLANDFORD', 'MA'),
    ('01009', 'BONDSVILLE', 'MA'),
    ('01010', 'BRIMFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01011', 'CHESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01012', 'CHESTERFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01013', 'CHICOPEE', 'MA'),
    ('01014', 'CHICOPEE', 'MA'),
    ('01020', 'CHICOPEE', 'MA'),
    ('01021', 'CHICOPEE', 'MA'),
    ('01022', 'CHICOPEE', 'MA'),
    ('01026', 'CUMMINGTON', 'MA'),
    ('01027', 'EASTHAMPTON', 'MA'),
    ('01028', 'EAST LONGMEADOW', 'MA'),
    ('01029', 'EAST OTIS', 'MA'),
    ('01030', 'FEEDING HILLS', 'MA'),
    ('01031', 'GILBERTVILLE', 'MA'),
    ('01032', 'GOSHEN', 'MA'),
    ('01033', 'GRANBY', 'MA'),
    ('01034', 'GRANVILLE', 'MA'),
    ('01035', 'HADLEY', 'MA'),
    ('01036', 'HAMPDEN', 'MA'),
    ('01037', 'HARDWICK', 'MA'),
    ('01038', 'HATFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01039', 'HAYDENVILLE', 'MA'),
    ('01040', 'HOLYOKE', 'MA'),
    ('01041', 'HOLYOKE', 'MA'),
    ('01050', 'HUNTINGTON', 'MA'),
    ('01053', 'LEEDS', 'MA'),
    ('01054', 'LEVERETT', 'MA'),
    ('01056', 'LUDLOW', 'MA'),
    ('01057', 'MONSON', 'MA'),
    ('01059', 'NORTH AMHERST', 'MA'),
    ('01060', 'NORTHAMPTON', 'MA'),
    ('01061', 'NORTHAMPTON', 'MA'),
    ('01062', 'FLORENCE', 'MA'),
    ('01063', 'NORTHAMPTON', 'MA'),
    ('01066', 'NORTH HATFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01068', 'OAKHAM', 'MA'),
    ('01069', 'PALMER', 'MA'),
    ('01070', 'PLAINFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01071', 'RUSSELL', 'MA'),
    ('01072', 'SHUTESBURY', 'MA'),
    ('01073', 'SOUTHAMPTON', 'MA'),
    ('01074', 'SOUTH BARRE', 'MA'),
    ('01075', 'SOUTH HADLEY', 'MA'),
    ('01077', 'SOUTHWICK', 'MA'),
    ('01079', 'THORNDIKE', 'MA'),
    ('01080', 'THREE RIVERS', 'MA'),
    ('01081', 'WALES', 'MA'),
    ('01082', 'WARE', 'MA'),
    ('01083', 'WARREN', 'MA'),
    ('01084', 'WEST CHESTERFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01085', 'WESTFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01086', 'WESTFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01088', 'WEST HATFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01089', 'WEST SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01090', 'WEST SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01092', 'WEST WARREN', 'MA'),
    ('01093', 'WHATELY', 'MA'),
    ('01094', 'WHEELWRIGHT', 'MA'),
    ('01095', 'WILBRAHAM', 'MA'),
    ('01096', 'WILLIAMSBURG', 'MA'),
    ('01097', 'WORONOCO', 'MA'),
    ('01098', 'WORTHINGTON', 'MA'),
    ('01101', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01102', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01103', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01104', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01105', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01106', 'LONGMEADOW', 'MA'),
    ('01107', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01108', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01109', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01111', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01115', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01116', 'LONGMEADOW', 'MA'),
    ('01118', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01119', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01128', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01129', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01133', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01138', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01139', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01144', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01151', 'INDIAN ORCHARD', 'MA'),
    ('01152', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01195', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01199', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01201', 'PITTSFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01202', 'PITTSFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01203', 'PITTSFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01220', 'ADAMS', 'MA'),
    ('01222', 'ASHLEY FALLS', 'MA'),
    ('01223', 'BECKET', 'MA'),
    ('01224', 'BERKSHIRE', 'MA'),
    ('01225', 'CHESHIRE', 'MA'),
    ('01226', 'DALTON', 'MA'),
    ('01227', 'DALTON', 'MA'),
    ('01229', 'GLENDALE', 'MA'),
    ('01230', 'GREAT BARRINGTON', 'MA'),
    ('01235', 'HINSDALE', 'MA'),
    ('01236', 'HOUSATONIC', 'MA'),
    ('01237', 'LANESBORO', 'MA'),
    ('01238', 'LEE', 'MA'),
    ('01240', 'LENOX', 'MA'),
    ('01242', 'LENOX DALE', 'MA'),
    ('01243', 'MIDDLEFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01244', 'MILL RIVER', 'MA'),
    ('01245', 'MONTEREY', 'MA'),
    ('01247', 'NORTH ADAMS', 'MA'),
    ('01252', 'NORTH EGREMONT', 'MA'),
    ('01253', 'OTIS', 'MA'),
    ('01254', 'RICHMOND', 'MA'),
    ('01255', 'SANDISFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01256', 'SAVOY', 'MA'),
    ('01257', 'SHEFFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01258', 'SOUTH EGREMONT', 'MA'),
    ('01259', 'SOUTHFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01260', 'SOUTH LEE', 'MA'),
    ('01262', 'STOCKBRIDGE', 'MA'),
    ('01263', 'STOCKBRIDGE', 'MA'),
    ('01264', 'TYRINGHAM', 'MA'),
    ('01266', 'WEST STOCKBRIDGE', 'MA'),
    ('01267', 'WILLIAMSTOWN', 'MA'),
    ('01270', 'WINDSOR', 'MA'),
    ('01301', 'GREENFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01302', 'GREENFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01330', 'ASHFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01331', 'ATHOL', 'MA'),
    ('01337', 'BERNARDSTON', 'MA'),
    ('01338', 'BUCKLAND', 'MA'),
    ('01339', 'CHARLEMONT', 'MA'),
    ('01340', 'COLRAIN', 'MA'),
    ('01341', 'CONWAY', 'MA'),
    ('01342', 'DEERFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01343', 'DRURY', 'MA'),
    ('01344', 'ERVING', 'MA'),
    ('01346', 'HEATH', 'MA'),
    ('01347', 'LAKE PLEASANT', 'MA'),
    ('01349', 'MILLERS FALLS', 'MA'),
    ('01350', 'MONROE BRIDGE', 'MA'),
    ('01351', 'MONTAGUE', 'MA'),
    ('01354', 'GILL', 'MA'),
    ('01355', 'NEW SALEM', 'MA'),
    ('01360', 'NORTHFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01364', 'ORANGE', 'MA'),
    ('01366', 'PETERSHAM', 'MA'),
    ('01367', 'ROWE', 'MA'),
    ('01368', 'ROYALSTON', 'MA'),
    ('01370', 'SHELBURNE FALLS', 'MA'),
    ('01373', 'SOUTH DEERFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01375', 'SUNDERLAND', 'MA'),
    ('01376', 'TURNERS FALLS', 'MA'),
    ('01378', 'WARWICK', 'MA'),
    ('01379', 'WENDELL', 'MA'),
    ('01380', 'WENDELL DEPOT', 'MA'),
    ('01420', 'FITCHBURG', 'MA'),
    ('01430', 'ASHBURNHAM', 'MA'),
    ('01431', 'ASHBY', 'MA'),
    ('01432', 'AYER', 'MA'),
    ('01434', 'DEVENS', 'MA'),
    ('01436', 'BALDWINVILLE', 'MA'),
    ('01438', 'EAST TEMPLETON', 'MA'),
    ('01440', 'GARDNER', 'MA'),
    ('01441', 'WESTMINSTER', 'MA'),
    ('01450', 'GROTON', 'MA'),
    ('01451', 'HARVARD', 'MA'),
    ('01452', 'HUBBARDSTON', 'MA'),
    ('01453', 'LEOMINSTER', 'MA'),
    ('01460', 'LITTLETON', 'MA'),
    ('01462', 'LUNENBURG', 'MA'),
    ('01463', 'PEPPERELL', 'MA'),
    ('01464', 'SHIRLEY', 'MA'),
    ('01467', 'STILL RIVER', 'MA'),
    ('01468', 'TEMPLETON', 'MA'),
    ('01469', 'TOWNSEND', 'MA'),
    ('01470', 'GROTON', 'MA'),
    ('01471', 'GROTON', 'MA'),
    ('01472', 'WEST GROTON', 'MA'),
    ('01473', 'WESTMINSTER', 'MA'),
    ('01474', 'WEST TOWNSEND', 'MA'),
    ('01475', 'WINCHENDON', 'MA'),
    ('01477', 'WINCHENDON SPRINGS', 'MA'),
    ('01501', 'AUBURN', 'MA'),
    ('01503', 'BERLIN', 'MA'),
    ('01504', 'BLACKSTONE', 'MA'),
    ('01505', 'BOYLSTON', 'MA'),
    ('01506', 'BROOKFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01507', 'CHARLTON', 'MA'),
    ('01508', 'CHARLTON CITY', 'MA'),
    ('01509', 'CHARLTON DEPOT', 'MA'),
    ('01510', 'CLINTON', 'MA'),
    ('01515', 'EAST BROOKFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01516', 'DOUGLAS', 'MA'),
    ('01517', 'EAST PRINCETON', 'MA'),
    ('01518', 'FISKDALE', 'MA'),
    ('01519', 'GRAFTON', 'MA'),
    ('01520', 'HOLDEN', 'MA'),
    ('01521', 'HOLLAND', 'MA'),
    ('01522', 'JEFFERSON', 'MA'),
    ('01523', 'LANCASTER', 'MA'),
    ('01524', 'LEICESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01525', 'LINWOOD', 'MA'),
    ('01526', 'MANCHAUG', 'MA'),
    ('01527', 'MILLBURY', 'MA'),
    ('01529', 'MILLVILLE', 'MA'),
    ('01531', 'NEW BRAINTREE', 'MA'),
    ('01532', 'NORTHBOROUGH', 'MA'),
    ('01534', 'NORTHBRIDGE', 'MA'),
    ('01535', 'NORTH BROOKFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01536', 'NORTH GRAFTON', 'MA'),
    ('01537', 'NORTH OXFORD', 'MA'),
    ('01538', 'NORTH UXBRIDGE', 'MA'),
    ('01540', 'OXFORD', 'MA'),
    ('01541', 'PRINCETON', 'MA'),
    ('01542', 'ROCHDALE', 'MA'),
    ('01543', 'RUTLAND', 'MA'),
    ('01545', 'SHREWSBURY', 'MA'),
    ('01546', 'SHREWSBURY', 'MA'),
    ('01550', 'SOUTHBRIDGE', 'MA'),
    ('01560', 'SOUTH GRAFTON', 'MA'),
    ('01561', 'SOUTH LANCASTER', 'MA'),
    ('01562', 'SPENCER', 'MA'),
    ('01564', 'STERLING', 'MA'),
    ('01566', 'STURBRIDGE', 'MA'),
    ('01568', 'UPTON', 'MA'),
    ('01569', 'UXBRIDGE', 'MA'),
    ('01570', 'WEBSTER', 'MA'),
    ('01571', 'DUDLEY', 'MA'),
    ('01580', 'WESTBOROUGH', 'MA'),
    ('01581', 'WESTBOROUGH', 'MA'),
    ('01582', 'WESTBOROUGH', 'MA'),
    ('01583', 'WEST BOYLSTON', 'MA'),
    ('01585', 'WEST BROOKFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01586', 'WEST MILLBURY', 'MA'),
    ('01588', 'WHITINSVILLE', 'MA'),
    ('01590', 'SUTTON', 'MA'),
    ('01601', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01602', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01603', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01604', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01605', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01606', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01607', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01608', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01609', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01610', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01611', 'CHERRY VALLEY', 'MA'),
    ('01612', 'PAXTON', 'MA'),
    ('01613', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01614', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01615', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01653', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01654', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01655', 'WORCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01701', 'FRAMINGHAM', 'MA'),
    ('01702', 'FRAMINGHAM', 'MA'),
    ('01703', 'FRAMINGHAM', 'MA'),
    ('01704', 'FRAMINGHAM', 'MA'),
    ('01705', 'FRAMINGHAM', 'MA'),
    ('01718', 'VILLAGE OF NAGOG WOO', 'MA'),
    ('01719', 'BOXBOROUGH', 'MA'),
    ('01720', 'ACTON', 'MA'),
    ('01721', 'ASHLAND', 'MA'),
    ('01730', 'BEDFORD', 'MA'),
    ('01731', 'HANSCOM AFB', 'MA'),
    ('01740', 'BOLTON', 'MA'),
    ('01741', 'CARLISLE', 'MA'),
    ('01742', 'CONCORD', 'MA'),
    ('01745', 'FAYVILLE', 'MA'),
    ('01746', 'HOLLISTON', 'MA'),
    ('01747', 'HOPEDALE', 'MA'),
    ('01748', 'HOPKINTON', 'MA'),
    ('01749', 'HUDSON', 'MA'),
    ('01752', 'MARLBOROUGH', 'MA'),
    ('01754', 'MAYNARD', 'MA'),
    ('01756', 'MENDON', 'MA'),
    ('01757', 'MILFORD', 'MA'),
    ('01760', 'NATICK', 'MA'),
    ('01770', 'SHERBORN', 'MA'),
    ('01772', 'SOUTHBOROUGH', 'MA'),
    ('01773', 'LINCOLN', 'MA'),
    ('01775', 'STOW', 'MA'),
    ('01776', 'SUDBURY', 'MA'),
    ('01778', 'WAYLAND', 'MA'),
    ('01784', 'WOODVILLE', 'MA'),
    ('01801', 'WOBURN', 'MA'),
    ('01803', 'BURLINGTON', 'MA'),
    ('01805', 'BURLINGTON', 'MA'),
    ('01806', 'WOBURN', 'MA'),
    ('01807', 'WOBURN', 'MA'),
    ('01808', 'WOBURN', 'MA'),
    ('01810', 'ANDOVER', 'MA'),
    ('01812', 'ANDOVER', 'MA'),
    ('01813', 'WOBURN', 'MA'),
    ('01815', 'WOBURN', 'MA'),
    ('01821', 'BILLERICA', 'MA'),
    ('01822', 'BILLERICA', 'MA'),
    ('01824', 'CHELMSFORD', 'MA'),
    ('01826', 'DRACUT', 'MA'),
    ('01827', 'DUNSTABLE', 'MA'),
    ('01830', 'HAVERHILL', 'MA'),
    ('01831', 'HAVERHILL', 'MA'),
    ('01832', 'HAVERHILL', 'MA'),
    ('01833', 'GEORGETOWN', 'MA'),
    ('01834', 'GROVELAND', 'MA'),
    ('01835', 'HAVERHILL', 'MA'),
    ('01840', 'LAWRENCE', 'MA'),
    ('01841', 'LAWRENCE', 'MA'),
    ('01842', 'LAWRENCE', 'MA'),
    ('01843', 'LAWRENCE', 'MA'),
    ('01844', 'METHUEN', 'MA'),
    ('01845', 'NORTH ANDOVER', 'MA'),
    ('01850', 'LOWELL', 'MA'),
    ('01851', 'LOWELL', 'MA'),
    ('01852', 'LOWELL', 'MA'),
    ('01853', 'LOWELL', 'MA'),
    ('01854', 'LOWELL', 'MA'),
    ('01860', 'MERRIMAC', 'MA'),
    ('01862', 'NORTH BILLERICA', 'MA'),
    ('01863', 'NORTH CHELMSFORD', 'MA'),
    ('01864', 'NORTH READING', 'MA'),
    ('01865', 'NUTTING LAKE', 'MA'),
    ('01866', 'PINEHURST', 'MA'),
    ('01867', 'READING', 'MA'),
    ('01876', 'TEWKSBURY', 'MA'),
    ('01879', 'TYNGSBORO', 'MA'),
    ('01880', 'WAKEFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01885', 'WEST BOXFORD', 'MA'),
    ('01886', 'WESTFORD', 'MA'),
    ('01887', 'WILMINGTON', 'MA'),
    ('01888', 'WOBURN', 'MA'),
    ('01889', 'NORTH READING', 'MA'),
    ('01890', 'WINCHESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01899', 'ANDOVER', 'MA'),
    ('01901', 'LYNN', 'MA'),
    ('01902', 'LYNN', 'MA'),
    ('01903', 'LYNN', 'MA'),
    ('01904', 'LYNN', 'MA'),
    ('01905', 'LYNN', 'MA'),
    ('01906', 'SAUGUS', 'MA'),
    ('01907', 'SWAMPSCOTT', 'MA'),
    ('01908', 'NAHANT', 'MA'),
    ('01910', 'LYNN', 'MA'),
    ('01913', 'AMESBURY', 'MA'),
    ('01915', 'BEVERLY', 'MA'),
    ('01921', 'BOXFORD', 'MA'),
    ('01922', 'BYFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01923', 'DANVERS', 'MA'),
    ('01929', 'ESSEX', 'MA'),
    ('01930', 'GLOUCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01931', 'GLOUCESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01936', 'HAMILTON', 'MA'),
    ('01937', 'HATHORNE', 'MA'),
    ('01938', 'IPSWICH', 'MA'),
    ('01940', 'LYNNFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01944', 'MANCHESTER', 'MA'),
    ('01945', 'MARBLEHEAD', 'MA'),
    ('01949', 'MIDDLETON', 'MA'),
    ('01950', 'NEWBURYPORT', 'MA'),
    ('01951', 'NEWBURY', 'MA'),
    ('01952', 'SALISBURY', 'MA'),
    ('01960', 'PEABODY', 'MA'),
    ('01961', 'PEABODY', 'MA'),
    ('01965', 'PRIDES CROSSING', 'MA'),
    ('01966', 'ROCKPORT', 'MA'),
    ('01969', 'ROWLEY', 'MA'),
    ('01970', 'SALEM', 'MA'),
    ('01971', 'SALEM', 'MA'),
    ('01982', 'SOUTH HAMILTON', 'MA'),
    ('01983', 'TOPSFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('01984', 'WENHAM', 'MA'),
    ('01985', 'WEST NEWBURY', 'MA'),
    ('02018', 'ACCORD', 'MA'),
    ('02019', 'BELLINGHAM', 'MA'),
    ('02020', 'BRANT ROCK', 'MA'),
    ('02021', 'CANTON', 'MA'),
    ('02025', 'COHASSET', 'MA'),
    ('02026', 'DEDHAM', 'MA'),
    ('02027', 'DEDHAM', 'MA'),
    ('02030', 'DOVER', 'MA'),
    ('02031', 'EAST MANSFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('02032', 'EAST WALPOLE', 'MA'),
    ('02035', 'FOXBORO', 'MA'),
    ('02038', 'FRANKLIN', 'MA'),
    ('02040', 'GREENBUSH', 'MA'),
    ('02041', 'GREEN HARBOR', 'MA'),
    ('02043', 'HINGHAM', 'MA'),
    ('02044', 'HINGHAM', 'MA'),
    ('02045', 'HULL', 'MA'),
    ('02047', 'HUMAROCK', 'MA'),
    ('02048', 'MANSFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('02050', 'MARSHFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('02051', 'MARSHFIELD HILLS', 'MA'),
    ('02052', 'MEDFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('02053', 'MEDWAY', 'MA'),
    ('02054', 'MILLIS', 'MA'),
    ('02055', 'MINOT', 'MA'),
    ('02056', 'NORFOLK', 'MA'),
    ('02059', 'NORTH MARSHFIELD', 'MA'),
    ('02060', 'NORTH SCITUATE', 'MA'),
    ('02061', 'NORWELL', 'MA'),
    ('02062', 'NORWOOD', 'MA'),
    ('02065', 'OCEAN BLUFF', 'MA'),
    ('02066', 'SCITUATE', 'MA'),
    ('02067', 'SHARON', 'MA'),
    ('02070', 'SHELDONVILLE', 'MA'),
    ('02071', 'SOUTH WALPOLE', 'MA'),
    ('02072', 'STOUGHTON', 'MA'),
    ('02081', 'WALPOLE', 'MA'),
    ('02090', 'WESTWOOD', 'MA'),
    ('02093', 'WRENTHAM', 'MA'),
    ('02108', 'BOSTON', 'MA'),
    ('02109', 'BOSTON', 'MA'),
    ('02110', 'BOSTON', 'MA'),
    ('02111', 'BOSTON', 'MA'),
    ('02112', 'BOSTON', 'MA');

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `us_zip_codes` ENABLE KEYS */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

Compressing this data turns a 2.5mb file into 273kb.

Is there a way to send compressed query to MySql?

Comment: As I know from phpMyAdmin you can upload zip file. but anyways you can uncompress the file manually no?

Comment: I feel like you're asking the wrong question. First of all 2.5mb isn't much (it's actually a ridiculously small amount of data). If the problem is, that it's more than X mb, you can split the file. With phpmyadmin on your server you can upload compressed sql files. Now the real question is, what is it, you're actually trying to avoid and for what reason? Because so far, I don't really see a problem at all ...

Comment: Yeah, the real amount of data is about 1000 times that size.  I was just using a single table as an example to see if compression was possible.  Honestly it seems a little odd that it isn't possible, I would think that would be an often used feature if it was built in.

Comment: Since it is not possible to send a compressed file to a MySql server, the only answer that involved compression and communicating directly with the MySql Server was by Steve Chambers, I have awarded him the bounty.  This is not what I was asking for an may not actually work for me, but I feel it was the closest answer.  Haresh VidjaI, understand I can change the packet size to slightly increase speed by decreasing packet count, thank you.  Rick James, I also understand I can use another server to work whatever compression magic I'd like.  I was really trying to avoid using a separate server

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, **There is no way to send compressed query** to mysql server,

BUT

**You can increase size of data packet** for long string query.

To increase the max_allowed_packet, open

my.ini/my.cnf under [mysqld] section.

Once the change is done you would have to restart the server.

It should be something as below. you have to set 3mb instead of 2 mb

```
max_allowed_packet=1048576 or 1mb
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a shell script problem.

```
cmd-to-uncompress <dump.zip | mysql -uroot -p
```

(Since we don't know what you used to compress, I cannot be specific on the uncompress command or its arguments.)

You seem to be using Windows, so you need to get into the `cmd` window to run the script.

Answer (score 2):

The [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html) command line utility can be used to efficiently import data from a file (e.g. a file containing tab-separated values or a CSV file, depending on the `--fields-terminated-by` setting). The `--compress` option can be used to compress the data in transit, as stated in the documentation:

> Compress all information sent between the client and the server if both support compression.

Comment: That "compress" has nothing to do with whether the data file is compressed.

Comment: Sure but eliminating the extra characters such as brackets from the inserts will save a bit of space and the compression in transit may be useful if network bandwidth is a limitation.

Comment: Sure, `--compress` is a good idea; just that it does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: The OP's use case is moving a large table onto another server. This could be done by executing something like `mysqlimport --compress db_name \\oldservername\path\us_zip_codes.tsv` in a command window on the new server (assuming it's Windows and there is network connectivity). The `--compress` here may not be essential but it may help, e.g. with speed/reliability.